# Get Total No of. Connected Users in Room in Socket.io + multiple process/cluster

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io

I want to get no of connected users in socket.io and i am having multiple socket.io servers

For ex. when `user1` connects to `server1` and joins room `room1`

Below statements returns gives the connected Users list

then

```
io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room1"]
```

or

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms["room1"]
```

And also i  tried many other solutions available on SO, and google.

But when i use above statements  in `server2` it does not return anything.

How can i get no of connected user in all server for specific room ?

I am using socket.io-redis module to communication between multiple processes.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question? I have the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the sessions/rooms etc, you probably need to use redis.

Here there's the doc for using multiple nodes (which is what you have as far as I understand) and to use redis to pass events between one and the other nodes. http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#passing-events-between-nodes

And yes, to check the sessions in one room the following is correct `io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room1"]`.

Oops, just read now that you state about using socket.io-redis already. If it is configured properly it should work, at least it does for me.

Comment: this returns user count for that process only. I want aggregated count of all server for specific room

Comment: socket.io-redis is properly configured. Also if i send message to specific room from another process, all process receives message. So it is working properly

Comment: Hi Hiren, can you explain to us how did you configure your socket.io-redis? I'm trying to get the clients connected to a room in my cluster and I've not been able.

Comment: @HirenS. were you able to solve this issue, could you please tell us your solution?

Comment: Basically just use socket.io-redis and should work, socket.io-redis does the magic trick ;)